# Java Grouping Images

Tags: java

I'm working on a game and had someone propose a challenge for me that I am having trouble solving so I am now turning to the stack overflow community for some help. I am trying to create a game similar to Tanks. I currently have two images (the tank body and tank arm) that I move based on two lines of code. They challenged me to create a separated class for the tank where I upload both images but am only required to draw it onto my game panel once. That is, I will have the tank body and tank arm in the class and can do whatever I need to do to them in there, but when I go to draw it onto my game scree panel, I am only required to write one line of code that simply draws on that class.

For Example:

```
g.drawImage(tank1, nX1, nY1, null)
```

Rather than:

```
g.drawImage(tank1, nX1, nY1, null)
g.drawImage(tank1, nX1, nY1, null)
```

Any links or ideas as to what to do would be appreciated. Example code would be even better.

Comment: What's the point of drawing twice the same image on the same location?

Comment: Who "proposed the challenge" to you? And what's the challenge; I don't get it yet.

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is trivial.  Have the object contain both images.  Have the "draw" function for the object call the g.drawImage functions for each of the images in turn.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was what Ben was alluding to, but I could not quite understand their answer, so:

Draw both parts to one `tankImage`.  In the game, draw the one `tankImage`.